# Mixing communication methods for microservices

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, microservices

I am working on a project which is actually will be a better version of an old project. We want it to be scalable to be able to deal with high load. So we decided to go with microservices instead of monolithic. Then I started to do research about microservices, how they communicate, common design patterns and other things. Since I want my services to be scalable, event based communication made sense to me. So I decided to use kafka for this purpose.

We have much more services in the system but to simplify my question lets say I have 2 types of services which are work-node and master-node. I want both of them to be scalable. For now they are communicating over kafka.

My question : for a case I want to publish an event (produce a message on a topic) from master-node and get that event (consume from the topic) from all work-nodes. But for an other case I need to send a message to specific work-node. To be able to cover first case, all my work-nodes have different group ids in kafka and when a message published on a topic they all get that message. I know that I am not able to send a message to specific consumer with kafka. Since my nodes are scalable and their number can increase or decrease depending on the load, creating a topic for each node does not seem a good idea. My first solution was adding work-node id in message. So other work-nodes can ignore that message. Well it works but I don't think it is a good solution. My second solution is sending http request if I am going to send a message to specific node. But I don't know mixing 2 communication methods is a good solution.

What do you guys think about this problem. Is there a better solution that I am missing ? Or my whole design is going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is not an appropriate technology for the use case you describe. I would recommend using [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) which natively supports routing tasks to specific nodes as well as dozens of other features that messaging systems lack.

Feel free to join [Cadence Workflow slack channel](https://join.slack.com/t/uber-cadence/shared_invite/enQtNDczNTgxMjYxNDEzLTQyYjcxZDM2YTIxMTZkMzQ0NjgxYmI3OWY5ODhiOTliM2I5MzA4NTM4MjU4YzgzZDkwNGEzOTUzNTBlNDk3Yjc) if you have specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should able to. Consider regular Kafka flow. You have some consumer groups subscribed to the topic. Producer doesn't send message to specific partition until you specify.

[image: Regular Flow]

Now think about the scenario that you produce some message based on your algorithm to the specific partitions.

[image: Partitioned Flow]

- Message received from A
- some kind of algorithm like hashcode generated always 0 for A
- Message send to Partition 0
- Consumer 1 connected to Partiton 0
- Only Consumer 1 gets the message coming from A

Comment: I thought about this but there are some problems with this solution. Firstly I don't know how many nodes gonna be there. So the partition size needs to be dynamic. I need to add/remove partitions to the topic at any time. And removing partitions is not supported in kafka I believe (Correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Another problem is I can assign consumers to specific partitions but normally kafka and zookeeper does this by rebalancing. So I need to disable rebalance feature somehow. And this is not suggested I believe. And even if I can handle distrubuting consumers to desired partitions, the first problem will still be on the table. Another solution might be having thousands of partitions but I think it is not a good idea. Anything I am missing here ?